# Error on inserting data by using a View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I crate a web page to register new student. In order to register a student we have to supply data for 4 entities (tables). Those are Mother table, Father table, ContactPerson table and Student table.
I created a viewmodel by including all fields of above entities and try to insert data or register a student. My code works well.
But when I register a student of a parent who has already registered, I will feed data only for two tables Student and contactperson. I developed the logic and try to feed data but it fails and raises;

"SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.The statement has been terminated."
May I know what the mistake I have done?

My code logic of Insert is as follows;

```
        public ActionResult  Insert(StudentRegVM std)
        {
            using (_context) {  
                if (! (std.IsExist == "T")) //checks, are parents exist? or not
                { // this block works for new parents only
                    var m = new Mother();
                    var f = new Father();
                    m.NIC = std.NIC;
                    m.FName = std.FNameM;
                    m.DOB = std.DOBM;
                    m.Job = std.Job;
                    m.Office = std.Office;
                    m.Race = std.RaceM;
                    m.Religion = std.ReligionM;
                    m.Tel_Mob = std.Tel_Mob;
                    m.Tel_Off = std.Tel_Off;
                    f.NIC = std.NICF;
                    f.FName = std.FNameF;
                    f.DOB = std.DOBF;
                    f.Job = std.JobF;
                    f.Office = std.OfficeF;
                    f.Race = std.RaceF;
                    f.Religion = std.ReligionF;
                    f.Tel_Mob = std.Tel_Mob_F;
                    f.Tel_Off = std.Tel_Off_F;
                    _context.Add(m);
                    _context.Add(f);
                }
                var c = new ContactPerson();
                var s = new Student();
                c.Address = std.AddressCP;
                c.Name = std.NameCP;
                c.Relationship = std.Relationship;
                c.Tel = std.TelCP;
                c.Tel2 = std.Tel2CP;
                s.Add_No = std.Add_No;
                s.DateOfAdd = std.DateOfAdd;
                s.GradeOfAdd = std.GradeOfAdd;
                s.House = std.House;
                s.F_Name = std.F_Name;
                s.S_Name = std.S_Name;
                s.DOB = std.DOB;
                s.Race = std.Race;
                s.Religion = std.Religion;
                s.BloodGroup = std.BloodGroup;
                s.Tel_H = std.Tel_H;
                s.Address = std.Address;
                s.GND = std.GND;
                s.OtherDetails = std.OtherDetails;
//foriegn keys
                s.FatherId = std.NICF;
                s.MotherId = std.NIC;
                s.ContactPersonId = std.TelCP;
                s.ClassId = std.ClzId;  
//feeding data
                _context.Add( s);
                _context.Add(c);
                _context.SaveChanges();                                 
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

Comment: The contents of one or more of your fields exceed the maximum size set for it in the database.  Look at your schema and check field lengths then debug when it crashes to locate which one too long for the DB.

Comment: I think you must save changes when added parent.

Comment: I tried both suggestions above but not successful. Please note that when I try to Insert data to 4 tables it works well. But when I try to Insert only for s and c it fails.

Comment: Jon you are correct I found a silly mistake in my view file. Thank you.

Comment: Devil your suggestion may have a logical short come because it will lead to partially insert the data if the later part fail. So savechanges() should come at last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your parameter sizes against column sizes and the field(s) in question should be evident pretty quickly.